# Android saving activity state

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity which is send some data to the server at onCreate.My problem is that if I press on lock button on the phone the screen turning off as we all knew but when I press the lock button to turn on the button the screen will turn on and it sending the data again so it is replicating the data. I just need to send the data only one time.what to do .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the data in `onCreate` but only if `savedInstanceState` is null:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // send data in a background thread
    }
}
```

If the activity is re-created (your case), the `savedInstanceState` is not null and it will contain any statefull info you would need to set.

Comment: Thank you gunar.:) lemme test.

Comment: Thank You very much gunar.:) one more doubt i have .I am developing a trial version so i am checking the date with server.The checking is at First activities oncreate. but the problem is when i go to second activity there is a back button. when i press on that button obviously it will be go to the FIRST then it will check the date. I dont want to check the date every time I just need to check the date when the app starts that's it.! hope you can help me.!

Comment: Well, you could have a custom object (that you can reference as singleton from anywhere). That object can keep the info you need (date). So you're getting the date from server and set it in that object: `DateKeeper.getInstance().setDate(serverDate);`. The next time you want to get that date, you will check if date stored is null or not. If null, download it (this will be the first date downloaded); otherwise, don't download. Hope it makes sense ...

Comment: Probably you would reset it (`DateKeeper.getInstance().reset()`) when the first activity finishes. Call `reset()` on `finish`, not on `onDestroy`!.

Comment: Thank you gunar.I would like to add some transition effect between two activities is it possible on android 2.3 .?

Comment: Just search for `android activity transition animation` in Google. You'll get a lot of useful links.